# Having trouble with custom errors pages in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, http-status-code-404

Can't seem to get it working...it's still showing the default error pages...

using **RAILS 4**

Here is my code..

ErrorsController

```
def not_found
  render :status => 404
end

def unacceptable
  render :status => 422
end

def internal_error
  render :status => 500
end
```

Application.rb

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

Routes.rb

```
match "/404", :to => "errors#not_found", via: 'get'
match "/422", :to => "errors#unacceptable", via: 'get'
match "/500", :to => "errors#internal_error", via: 'get'
```

And i have the appropriate view with all those files

Why does it still render the default rails error messages?

Answer (score 6):

you can go to config/environments/development.rb and change the following line,

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

to

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

Although I haven't tried this out myself, it is supposed to enable error messages while in development. The default allows for you to see debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

Also be aware the the error pages are not displayed in a `:development` environment

Comment: But if you go to localhost:300/404 in the dev env it will render error pages...i understand you cant get to them by their intended purposes (going to a wrong url)

Comment: Why is this so? Make's it difficult to style it?? Guess i'll just make a random page and style it then transfer the code over to the error page lol LAME  Thanks @dtt101

Comment: Or maybe because the Routing Error -page is far more useful while developing? :P